# wordpress permanent link htaccess issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

## My WordPress site has permanent link issues - .htaccess

In the WordPress Permanent link section,
1) When I select the post name URL (**www.myworld.org/sample-post/**) it's not working. Actually it's throwing the **404 error** whenever linked to sub pages of the web site.
eg: www.myworld.org/aboutus/

2) When I place the custom link with %index.php% it works fine (**www.myworld.org/index.php/%postname%/**). However all the sub pages URL coming with index.php
eg: www.myworld.org/index.php/aboutus/

I want to get rid of the index.php in all the sub pages URL.

3) Actually my website files are placed into one separate folder on the root.
eg: **/newsite/...** (all WordPress files **wp-content**, **wp-include**, **wp-admin** etc.) 
Also I've placed **.htaccess** file inside **/newsite/**  directory along with other WordPress files.
eg:  **/newsite/.htaccess**

My .htaccess file below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ./index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Even I've .htaccess file However I've 404 page issue when change the permanent link to postname.
eg: www.myworld.org/sample-post/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change URL structure from Post Name to Plain and refresh your website ... once you have done check you front end page if it shows proper URLs, After doing this, revert back your Permalinks to Post Name ... hope that will fix your issue ... your .htaccess file is looking standard one at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've change to plain URL thne the sub page URL's appear with page id eg: **www.myworld.org/?page_id=17** plain its not giving the page name as i expected. eg: **www.myworld.org/aboutus/

Comment: However I've revert back to Postname then giving the same 404 error for sub pages.